Analogue of Lucas-Lehmer test for generalised Mersenne numbers
So, I have came up with a somewhat of a generalisation of Mersenne numbers
$\frac{n^p-1}{n-1}$
I have tried to come up with an analogue of Lucas-Lehmer test for such thing. The main idea of the original test is
$s_n=a^{2^n}+b^{2^n}$
Where $a,b=2\pm\sqrt{3}$
I can't come up with something similar but for $3^n$.
Similarly, extending the idea of hyperperfect numbers (discussed here (those are also connected with hyperperfect numbers discussed here arXiv:1008.0155)
$n^p-(n-1)$
So, my question is whether were generalised tests invented before and if so, where can I find info about them? I have tried to do some research myself but did not manage to find anything useful

It’s Lucas with a c

These numbers are called base-$n$ repunits. (Their base-$n$ expansions are a string of ones; as you are no doubt aware, these numbers can only be prime if $p$ is.)  In general, there are plenty of efficient probable-prime tests for these (or even arbitrary) numbers; the hard part is proving that there are no pseudoprimes.  I don't know whether your particular test is known, but it would certainly be a major achievement to prove that it never gives a false positive.

The book by Brillhart et al., Factorizations of $b^n\pm1$, https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-22/ has a long section in the beginning about techniques for testing such numbers for primality and factoring them if they are composite.

Have you had a look at that book, Java?
